# Django-MySQL enable Row_Format=Compress with syncdb

Tags: mysql, django, syncdb

I have an application in Django and MySQL, in my model I have several fields specified as TextField, when i run syncdb the tables for my model are created and the specified columns are created with longtext data type, so far so good.

But when I try, enter information in the table I get the following error

> DatabaseError: (1118, 'Row size too large. The maximum row size for
>   the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change
>   some columns to TEXT or BLOBs ")

I changed the column type to Text and Blob, and did not solve the problem.

I've been reading about this error and is due to more than 8126bytes income information by row. So I changed the configuration of MySQL to work with the file type Barracuda instead of Antepode, which I have been reading allows compression of sending information over to a different file.

But this did not solve the problem, in the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html) tells me that I have to specify `ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED` when i create the table, but this is done by syncdb,

Is there way to specify these settings when syncdb creates the tables or I have to create the tables manually without using syncdb?

Any other suggestions would be welcome, in my application I have to store multiple sheets and reports. I have defined a column in my table by section of the document.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the error to add big data rows in MySQL using innodb

> DatabaseError: (1118, 'Row size too large. The maximum row size for
>   the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change
>   some columns to TEXT or BLOBs ")

first we have to set the file format to Barracuda and enable one file per table global variable in MySQL with:

> SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = Barracuda;
>      SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format_check = ON;
>      SET GLOBAL innodb_format_max = Barracuda;
>      SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = ON;

i used phpmyadmin for querys.

Then after run syncdb we go to the table where we have the problem with the large rows, go to the tab Operations->Table Options and then modify 'ROW_FORMAT' to 'COMPRESS'.

i hope this was helpful